# if previously logged in on app using android studio

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-studio

OK so i am sort of new to android studio and java 
i am attempting to have an activity that checks if the user was previously logged in via, the login option, google or facebook 
if they were i want them to be redirected to the user page
if they are not i want them to be redirected to the login/register page

this is what my mainActivity.java file looks like

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //see if the person is logged in by getting their preference
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    //Get the value for the counter
    int counter = app_preferences.getInt("counter, 0");


    else
    {
        // condition false take it user on login form
    }


}
```

}

//if the person is not logged in go to welcome page
//if person is logged in go to home page
i have tried using youtube but have not gotten any information

Comment: Have you tried Facebook developer's tutorial:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android
Or even Android Hive:
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/, Do some research.

Answer (score 1):

You can store a boolean value at SharedPrefrence, then set it like this:

```
// Some where when the app first installed    
boolean loggedIn = false;

SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt(getString(R.string.save_log_in_state), loggedIn);
editor.commit();
```

when the user log in successfully using facebook, twitter .. etc.

and get it like this:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int defaultValue = false;
boolean loggedIn = sharedPref.getBoolean(getString(R.string.save_log_in_state), defaultValue);
```

You may use a splash screen to load in 5 sec or so, while the app determine to show the login/register activity or the user is already logged in.

Reference for Shared Preferences: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading the facebook developers page which giving a nice tutorial about integrating Facebook login in your Android app:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started